# Magento-2 order is not created after Successful Payment - PayPal

Tags: magento2.2.2, payment, paypal, order-success-page

In my Magento website, Customer has placed an Order, PayPal received the amount with the Magento Order ID. But still, Customer didn't get to reach the Success page. Also that Order not listing at the backend as well.

I have searched about this issue, and some of them faced the same issue, and suggested me to disable  **Asynchronous indexing** from **Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Grid Settings > Asynchronous indexing**.

But I can't get the reason, why the issue happening, at what case, can anyone guide me on this.?

It would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue; Paypal & Stripe payments taken, No Order Confirmation Page, No Magento Backend Record, and NO errors showed up on Frontend nor Error Log!

**The Reason:** Faulty Plugin! In my case: https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-store-credit-extension.html . Took a good while to figure out.

**Solution:** Disable all your plugins, and test, then narrow down and find the culprit.

```
php bin/magento module:disable VendorName_ModuleName1 VendorName_ModuleName2
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be times when intensive sales on a storefront occur at the same time that Magento is performing intensive order processing.

So Magento to distinguish these two traffic patterns on the database level and conflicts between read and write operations in the corresponding tables.

Orders are placed in temporary storage and moved in bulk to the Order Management grid without any collisions.

I hope it helps!

Comment: But there is no record in Magento tables to those orders. Only from PayPal, I can get those order ids.

Comment: Try to place order using other payment method like check / cash on delivery. and check order is display in grid or not.

Comment: Only some times its coming. Even after that, we have placed an order using PayPal.

Comment: @ShajithaBanu - I'm having same issue. How did you resolve?

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons why a customer is not reaching the success page and why the order is not listed at the backend after PayPal has received the payment with the Magento Order ID. One possible reason could be the asynchronous indexing setting in Magento, which can cause orders to not show up immediately in the backend. Disabling asynchronous indexing may help resolve this issue.

However, it's important to investigate the root cause of the issue further to prevent it from happening again in the future. This could involve reviewing server logs, checking for any conflicts with third-party modules or custom code, and ensuring that all Magento and PayPal settings are properly configured. It may also be helpful to reach out to Magento or PayPal support for further assistance in troubleshooting the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem with Magento 2.2.6

PayPal Module: i-ways PayPal Plus

The problem accures only with PayPal and not with every order. Success page is never loading and the article is still in the shopping cart.

**After disabling the Magento Full Page Cache everything works as it should. ;)**